# Android - top level gradle task with parameter type:Exec runs automatically on build, why?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I have a task that runs a shell script. It resides in my top level gradle file only. So the gradle file im talking about can be seen here:

[image]

Now for the interesting part, i have  a task in the file called copyFiles which just runs a simple shell script to copy files.  Im going to show you my entire build.gradle top level file now:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

task copyFiles(type:Exec) {
    exec {
        commandLine 'sh', './copyFiles.sh'
    }
}
```

Now whenever i build the project this task gets executed. As long as i build the project (aka compile it) this task runs. Is that normal ? i put a print line in there to make sure and yes it gets run everytime i build the 'app' module.  Is this normal. What if i wanted it not to do that ?

UPDATE: Now after researching i found that some gradle tasks can be executed right away without being invoked if defined like this:

```
//option 1, this runs right away on build
    task foo(type: Exec) {
    // this is configuration
    // i.e. it runs regardless
}
//option 2 this runs only when called on
  task bar(type: Exec) << {
    // this is execution
    // i.e. it only runs if you call the task
}
```

So then i thought i'd try the same thing with :

```
task copyFiles(type: Copy) {
    from '/Users/myuser/Documents/androidstudio/MyApplication/Common/'
    into '/Users/myuser/Documents/androidstudio/MyApplication/app/src/main/assets'
}
```

but to my surprise it does not get run on its own. I actually have to call it ? How is this different then type:Exec ? why is there no consistency ?

UPDATE:

I wrote a blog about [the gradle lifecycle](http://j2emanue.blogspot.ca/) for anyone who needs help after my analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have to read about the [build lifecycle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html). When you run your build, this build goes through 3 phases: Initialization, Configuration and Execution.

When you declare a closure as:

```
task foo(type: Exec) {
    // this is configuration
    // i.e. it runs regardless
}
```

then this closure is executed for all the task at the configuration phase, that is why your print line is always called, even if a task shell not be executed. It's just a part of the whole configuration.

But if you declare a closure with `<<`, as:

```
task bar(type: Exec) << {
    // this is execution
    // i.e. it only runs if you call the task
}
```

it's executed at the execution phase. Actually, `<<` is equals to `doLast` for the task.

Furthermore, then you use a `exec {}` notation within a task, you create a execution subtask within it.

So, if you don't want to run it at the configuration, then just use it with the `<<`, or don't call an additional `exec` task within a task, which is by itself of type `Exec` and just properly configure it, like:

```
task copyFiles(type:Exec) {
   commandLine 'sh', './copyFiles.sh'
}
```

Comment: This is deprecated now in latest gradle with error "Could not find method leftShift() for arguments".